# density of 0 digits in the powers of a number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

for $c>0$,is there $n,(n,10)=1$ such that for all k, 
number of o digits in the decimal representation of n^k>c.(number of digits in the decimal representation of n^k)

Answer (score 2):

Let $c<1$. Let $k$ be any integer satisfying the inequality $k\ge\frac2{1-c}$; then it’s easily checked that $1-c\ge\frac2k>\frac2{k+2}$, so $\frac{k}{k+2}=1-\frac2{k+2}>c$. Now let $n=10^k+1$; clearly $\left(10^k+1,10\right)=1$. Moreover, $n$ has $k+2$ digits, $k$ of which are $0$, so the ratio of $0$ digits to total digits is $\frac{k}{k+2}>c$. Of course we cannot take $c\ge 1$, so this is the best possible result.